# Parse cannot be resolved

Tags: android, parse-platform

i've got a problem, i've an android application, i want to implement push notification with parse
i follow this tutorial on parse site
https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart?onboard=#parse_push/android/existing

but when i put

```
Parse.initialize(this, "xxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxx");
```

ecplise says "Parse cannot be resolved"

how can i solve this?
and what is "build.gradle" ?

Answer (score 2):

It seem Parse library not configured..

try add Parse library first on your project

Parse provide .jar library.. check on your Parse SDK (download it first from [here](https://parse.com/docs/downloads))

then copy these library then put in **libs** folder on your project
something like these, 
[image: add libray]

then right click .jar file and then **add as library**

your project will rebuild, or you can try **Build > Make Project**

Answer (score 1):

i have used parse and successfully sent push notifications.

Try this,just get your keys from parse.com :- https://github.com/FoamyGuy/ParseNotificationExample
Get the above project, import into eclipse and give your keys(from your developer console in parse).